# this is javascript array with havaing objects whenever i try to fetch data of notes in the console it shows undefined but in react it work perfectly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const notes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      content: "HTML is easy",
      date: "2019-05-30T17:30:31.098Z",
      important: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      content: "Browser can execute only JavaScript",
      date: "2019-05-30T18:39:34.091Z",
      important: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      content: "GET and POST are the most important methods of HTTP protocol",
      date: "2019-05-30T19:20:14.298Z",
      important: true,
    },
  ]

const res = notes.map(note=>note.content) // cont res = // was added by Carsten

console.log(res) // added by Carsten
```

Comment: Your script should work exactly as it is.

Comment: When running your snippet everything works fine